# Resource file in assets can not be found

Tags: android

I was developing a map based app and used a library named **AMap.jar** to initialize map. The library contains a file named `ap.data` which will be placed in the assets folder during runtime. Mostly, my app went well. But occasionally,`ap.data` just can't be found and result in an **FileNotFoundException**.

Plus, once the situation comes up, it can't be fixed even though I reinstall the app through Android Studio.

How can I fix this?

I  have a suspicion that this have something to do with **Instant Run** of Android Studio.

Has anyone ever had similar situations?

Comment: can you copy paste you full Exception

Comment: Show your code where you are loading the data from assets.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I was forbidden to post more than 2 pictures for my reputation is less than 10.

Comment: I can only post the link of the pictures.[the full exception][1]
[the map library I use][2]
[where the libray use "ap.data" in assets][3]
[how the library read file in assets][4]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/a8PjY.jpg
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uMn2c.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/IIaFp.png
  [4]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/R7CMT.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make your sure code is bug-free.

Second, observer behavior like as you said when your app runs successfully it should be keep on running without any problem until next build or till you go out of your app, if not then it means there is a problem in your code.

If your app keep on running without any problem util restart or till next build it mean you are suffering from instant-run bug and they are like

- Inside Run TAB next to anroid-monitor, sometimes it shows, `no changes to deploy` mean changes in code has not added to your app
- Sometimes it runs the new app and when you restart your app it shows the old one.

**Solution :**

Update to latest Build because this tends to happen more in older releases.

Disable instant run under your project settings.

Try to use the latest studio release which has totally improved instant-run .

Comment: Thanks for your advice,I think this will work for me.

Answer (score 0):

To access the file from assets :

```
 AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = assetManager.open("foo.txt");
                if ( inputStream != null)
                    Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: I referred to the source code of the map library, and I found same codes just as above.